Live server in VS Code showing listing directory instead of React app
I'm new to React and I'm currently following a code-along using create-react-app and node/npm. I've had no issue for a couple week but today when I select "go live" from App.js it shows me a listing directory. If I go live from the index.html I get a white screen. I've looked at other solutions and I either don't understand them, or they don't work.
These are the items in the directory:
build
node_modules
public
src
package-lock.json
package.json
README.md
I've tried going live using index.html and app.js. I've made sure npm is updated. I've made sure that nothing was open in my workspace aside from either index.html or app.js.

You're probably running the index.html file in your "public" folder, when you should be running the one in your "build" folder. In VSCode find the index.html file in your "build" folder and right click it, then choose "open with live server".
But I have to ask why are you using the live server extension instead of using the webpack-dev-server that comes bundled with your create-react-app? It doesn't make sense to run a live server with a production build, that defeats the whole purpose of having a live server to begin with. What you should be doing is using the development server. From your terminal go to your project's root directory (the one where your package.json file resides) and run this command npm start, that should start your development server and opens a tab in your default browser with an adress of "http://localhost:3000".

That makes sense. When I restarted my PC I forgot to start npm again.
